# Не корректное чтение ID3v2 тегов

Tags: c#, mp3, id3v2

Здравствуйте, в своей программе хочу реализовать чтение ID3 тегов. Написал несколько классов для этого (ещё не дописал), но судя по результатам, даже уже написанное работает не совсем корректно. Часть кода я писал не сам, а нашел его в сети, и он мне не очень понятен, так что если кто знает, прошу объяснить его.

Классы которые на данный момент есть:

1. ID3TagReader - главный класс, который определяет какая версия тегов находиться в файле.
2. ID3v1 - осуществляет чтение ID3v1 тегов, если именно они записаны в файл.
3. ID3v2 - осуществляет чтение ID3v2 тегов, если именно они записаны в файл.
4. MainHeader - читает заголовок ID3v2 тега.
5. FrameHeader - читает заголовки фреймов.
6. FrameData - читает записанный тег в фрейме.

Прошу высказать свою критику касательно ниже приведенного кода("грамотность", эффективность(насколько, относительно других подобных программ, процесс чтения нагружает ПК), и сам по себе алгоритм чтения), а также объяснить помеченные комментариями строки кода.

**ID3TagReader:**

```
public class ID3TagReader
{
    private FileStream fs;
    private ID3v1 ID3v1;
    private ID3v2 ID3v2;
    private string album;
    private BitmapImage albumArt;
    private string artist;
    private string title;

    public ID3TagReader(string path)
    {
        fs      = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //Непосредственно с этим файлстримом работают все остальные классы.
//Думаю далее все понятно.
        ID3v1   = new ID3v1(ref fs);
        ID3v2   = new ID3v2(ref fs);

        if (ID3v2.HasTag)
        {
            album       = ID3v2.Album;
            albumArt    = ID3v2.AlbumArt;
            artist      = ID3v2.Artist;
            title       = ID3v2.Title;
        }
        else if (ID3v1.HasTag)
        {
            album       = ID3v1.Album;
            albumArt    = null;
            artist      = ID3v1.Artist;
            title       = ID3v1.Title;
        }
        else
        {
            album       = "Error";
            albumArt    = null;
            artist      = "Error";
            title       = "Error";
        }

        ID3v1 = null;
        ID3v2 = null;
        fs.Close();
    }

    public string Album
    {
        get
        {
            return album;
        }
    }
    public BitmapImage AlbumArt
    {
        get
        {
            return albumArt;
        }
    }
    public string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return artist;
        }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

**ID3v1:**

```
public class ID3v1 // С чтением ID3v1 у меня никаких проблем не возникло, соответственно вопросов тут нет.
{
    private byte[] tags = new byte[128];

    public ID3v1(ref FileStream fs)
    {
        fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.Read(tags, 0, 128);
    }

    public bool HasTag
    {
        get
        {
            if (new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(tags).Substring(0, 3).Trim().Equals("TAG"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                tags = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Album
    {
        get
        {
            return new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(tags).Substring(63, 30).Trim();
        }
    }
    public string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(tags).Substring(33, 30).Trim();
        }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(tags).Substring(3, 30).Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

**ID3v2:**

```
public class ID3v2
{
    private string album;
    private BitmapImage albumArt;
    private string artist;
    private string title;

    private MainHeader header;
    private FrameHeader frameHeader;
    private FrameData frameData;

    private int size;
    private int position;

    public ID3v2(ref FileStream fs)
    {
        header = new MainHeader(ref fs);
        size = header.Size;
        position = 10;

        if (header.Marker.Equals("ID3"))
        {
            while (size > 0)
            {
                frameHeader = new FrameHeader(ref fs, position);
                frameData = new FrameData(ref fs, (position + 10), frameHeader.FrameSize);
                position = frameHeader.FrameSize + 10;

                switch (header.MajorVersion)
// Тут ещё не реализована
//логика конвертации массивов байт в текстовые значения и изображения,
//но поверхностно я понимаю как это сделать.
                {
                    case 3:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            throw new System.NotSupportedException("ID3v2.2 is not supported yet.");
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            throw new System.NotSupportedException("This version of ID3v2 is not supported yet.");
                        }
                }

                size = size - position; //position имеет такое же значение
//как и размер фрейма, не корректность работы заключается в том, что размер
//всего тега "size" является числом с 5-ю, а то и 6-ю знаками, а размер
//фрейма состоит, зачастую, из двух знаков, но при этом цикл повторяется
//лишь 2-3 раза.
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasTag
    {
        get
        {
            if (header.Marker.Equals("ID3"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Album
    { 
        get
        {
            return album;
        }
    }
    public BitmapImage AlbumArt
    {
        get
        {
            return albumArt;
        }
    }
    public string Artist
    {
        get
        {
            return artist;
        }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainHeader:**

```
public class MainHeader
{
    private byte[] header = new byte[10];

    public MainHeader(ref FileStream fs)
    {
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Read(header, 0, 10);
    }

    public string Marker
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(header).Substring(0, 3).Trim();
        }
    }
    public int MajorVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return header[3];
        }
    }
    public int MinorVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return header[4];
        }
    }
    // Далее флаги, этот код я нашел в сети, поэтому прошу объяснить его по подробнее. 
    public bool Unsynchronisation
    {
        get
        {
            return ((header[5] & 0x80) == 0x80);
        }
    }
    public bool ExtendedHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return ((header[5] & 0x40) == 0x40);
        }
    }
    public bool ExperimentalIndicator
    {
        get
        {
            return ((header[5] & 0x20) == 0x20);
        }
    }
    public bool FooterPresent
    {
        get
        {
            return ((header[5] & 0x10) == 0x10);
        }
    }
    // Так же не очень понял что это за Sync-safe integer, которым является размер всех тегов, и как происходит конвертация байтовых значений в него.
    public int Size
    {
        get
        {
            return (header[9] & 0x7f) | (header[8] & 0x7f) << 7 | (header[7] & 0x7f) << 14 | (header[6] & 0x7f) << 21;
        }
    }
}
```

**FrameHeader:**

```
public class FrameHeader // Тут те же вопросы, что и по поводу MainHeader
{
    private byte[] frameHeader = new byte[10];

    public FrameHeader(ref FileStream fs, int position)
    {
        fs.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.Read(frameHeader, 0, 10);
    }

    public string FrameID
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(frameHeader).Substring(0, 4).Trim();
        }
    }
    public int FrameSize
    {
        get
        {
            return (frameHeader[7] & 0x7f) | (frameHeader[6] & 0x7f) << 7 | (frameHeader[5] & 0x7f) << 14 | (frameHeader[4] & 0x7f) << 21;
        }
    }
    public bool TagAlterPreservation
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[8] & 0x80) == 0x80);
        }
    }
    public bool FileAlterPreservation
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[8] & 0x40) == 0x40);
        }
    }
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[8] & 0x20) == 0x20);
        }
    }
    public bool GroupingIdentity
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[9] & 0x20) == 0x20);
        }
    }
    public bool Compression
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[9] & 0x80) == 0x80);
        }
    }
    public bool Encryption
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[9] & 0x40) == 0x40);
        }
    }
    public bool Unsynchronisation
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[9] & 0x01) == 0x01);
        }
    }
    public bool DataLengthIndicator
    {
        get
        {
            return ((frameHeader[9] & 0x03) == 0x03);
        }
    }
}
```

**FrameData:**

```
public class FrameData // Тут всё должно быть ясно.
{
    private byte[] data;

    public FrameData(ref FileStream fs, int position, int size)
    {
        data = new byte[size]; 
        fs.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin); //Так как этот класс работает в цикле, позиция для чтения очередного тега будет обновляться.
        fs.Read(data, 0, size);
    }

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Это весь код, который есть на данный момент.
И так, с нетерпением жду ваших поправок, отзывов и ответов.

Comment: Очень много вопросов, и не очень понятно, что нужно... Совет такой - прежде чем кодировать id3v2 да и вообще что угодно, нужно четко понимать с чем имеете дело. Поэтому советую прежде прочитать спецификацию.

Comment: По synchsafe. В mp3 байт 0х11111111 является байтом синхронизации, поэтому его появление в теге - это плохо. Чтобы избежать этого, числа хранятся в формате synchsafe integer, где первый бит всегда занулён (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchsafe)

Comment: @elp87, я читал спецификацию ID3v2, и в принципе понял что к чему. Не до конца лишь разобрался в кодировке текстовых фреймов, в зависимости от флагов и версии ID3v2. А по поводу syncsafe integer хотел только узнать, правильно ли я реализовал его чтение. Другие вопросы по прежнему актуальны. Да и я не прошу ответить на все вопросы, я был бы рад если бы кто то разъяснил мне хотя бы половину из них :)

Comment: @elp87, если я не ошибаюсь, то кажется я видел ваш код для работы с ID3v2 на GitHub :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу флагов заголовка. Там каждый бит отвечает за определённое значение. На примере флага *ExperimentalIndicator* основного заголовка:

```
return ((header[5] & 0x20) == 0x20);
```

За этот флаг отвечает третий бит, и нам нужно получить его значение. Для этого применяем операцию побитовое И (оператор &) байта флагов с маской 0х20, т.е. 00100000. Если этот флаг равен 1, то в результате операции получится 0х20; если 0, то 0х00.

---

Далее, по поводу synchsafe integer.

```
return (header[9] & 0x7f) | (header[8] & 0x7f) << 7 | (header[7] & 0x7f) << 14 | (header[6] & 0x7f) << 21;
```

Первый бит каждого байта такого числа всегда установлен в 0, поэтому не несет смысловой нагрузки. Значимыми остаются остальные 7 бит. Их и нужно слепить в единое число без разрывов. Для этого от каждого байта отбрасываем незначимый бит с помощью операции `byte & 0x7f` и делаем побитовый сдвиг влево на 0/7/14/21 разрядов

---

```
while (size > 0)
{
    //...
    size = size - position; 
}
```

Естественно у Вас здесь ошибка. Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
while (size > position)
{
    //...
    position += frameSize // где frameSize - размер текущего фрейма
}
```

Просто в Вашем случае шаг в условии делается не на размер фрейма, а на размер тега, который уже был прочитан

Comment: Спасибо, по факту вы дали ответ на самые приоритетные для меня вопросы. Пожалуй осталось только углубится в спецификацию и правильно прочесть теги. Остался ещё один вопрос, о котором я, к сожалению, только сейчас вспомнил - касательно APIC, в ID3v2.4 есть 21 тип изображений, а как мне достать именно "Cover (front)"?

Comment: Фреймов APIC в теге может быть несколько. Вас интересует тот, у которого  байт "тип изображения" (Picture type) имеет значение 0x03

Comment: Теперь все стало на свои места, ещё раз большое вам спасибо.